# How do I add my Outlook School Email Account to Elementary OS?

Tags: pantheon-mail

I am trying to add my school email address to Elementary OS 6, and I can't get it to configure.  I've tried the Microsoft settings for Outlook (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/pop-imap-and-smtp-settings-8361e398-8af4-4e97-b147-6c6c4ac95353), but that doesn't log me in.  When I log in at Outlook.com on Firefox, it takes me to a page from my school, and then I log in there, and then I can access my email through the browser.  Any thoughts on how to get this working in the Elementary OS Mail app?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This will be different for many universities, so you may have to double check this with the technical support staff where you study. Based on what you've said, it sounds as though there is some SSO authentication required. Here are the IMAP settings that *generally* work for situations like this:

Incoming IMAP:

| Setting | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Server hostname | `outlook.office365.com` |
| Port | `993` |
| SSL | SSL/TLS |
| Authentication | Oauth2 |

Outgoing IMAP:

| Setting | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Server hostname | `smtp.office365.com` |
| Port | `587` |
| SSL | `STARTTLS` |
| Authentication | Oauth2 |

The username for both incoming and outgoing will be your email address.

Once this is configured, the system will try to connect to the server. Because the Authentication is `Oauth2`, you will be presented with a login screen where you can enter the username and password for your school.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using BlueMail, which can be installed as a snap.  I've yet to be able to ever get an account working on eOS Mail, but BlueMail never fails.  I'm currently accessing multiple accounts through it, including outlook.com.